# How can I change the vimrc console font

Tags: fonts, vim

I connect to my linux box via putty.  I've been able to modify the color scheme via my vimrc file, but how can I change the console font?  I see an option for guifont but I am not using a GUI...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the console font from vim.  You can change the font in Putty.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Vim [documentation](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Change_font?action=edit&section=1)

> Console Vim uses whatever font the console/terminal is using. Changing the font in your terminal is done differently depending on your system and the terminal in use.

So if you want to change vim console font you need to change your terminal font.